# Clicking on links without an ID or name

Tags: java, html, selenium, htmlunit

I would like to locate the following anchor but not by its href. I have tried Htmlnit and Selenium. What i want to do is as mentioned locate the anchor and clicking on it,  followed by getting the url i was directed to. However besides from i cannot locate the anchor and clicking on it, i get a bunch of error messaging complaining about the java script on the website.

< a href="/filingFrameset.asp?FileName=0001193125%2D14%2D302730%2Etxt&FilePath=%5C2014%5C08%5C08%5C&CoName=GENPACT+LTD&FormType=10%2DQ&RcvdDate=8%2F8%2F2014&pdf=" onmouseover="window.status='10-Q - GENPACT LTD - 8/8/2014'; return true;" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true;" target="fetchFiling">10-Q

WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
okt 05, 2014 3:18:41 EM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is your problem to get the current url of the page your are on? Is your problem to find the link you can click on? Generally you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to know the URL of the current Page.

You could use:

```
<script>

alert(window.location.href);

</script>
```